# Adding a floating image to a thumbnails

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody tell me why if I make a complex thumbnail (image+text+buttons..) using bootstrap, and if I want to add and overlapping image floating to the right (like the sale tag for the e-shop item) using .pull-right class so in result to get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C73YB.png), the image doesn't overlap - it stays as if I would just simply places it there(like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDI1B.png))?

Comment: I have made an [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyRWK/) page, please, if you can, make any changes there.

Comment: looking to achieve something like: http://jsfiddle.net/XyRWK/3/ ?

Comment: If that comment answers the question, could you @SiGanteng please repost it as an answer and you Astro mark it as accepted?